# What is rrd.dir in log4j for?

Tags: configuration, log4j

I came across rdd.dir in log4j properties file by the author of website http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html

Does anyone know what directory is this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [RRD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rrdtool) Support